# Finding the volume of a 3d region

Tags: calculus

Okay so I'm asked to find the volume of $E=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2 \leq 2y, 0 \leq z \leq \sqrt(x^2+y^2) \}$ using cylindrical coordinates. That first inequality is equivalent to $x^2+(y-1)^2 \leq 1$ thus $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and the 2nd inequality is just $0 \leq z \leq r$. With no bounds on $\theta $, I get $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi}{ \int_{0}^{1}{ \int_{0}^{r}{rdzdrd\theta}}}=\frac {2\pi}{3} $$ Why is this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates, the inequality $x^2+y^2 \le 2y$ becomes $r^2 \le 2r\sin \theta$, i.e. $0 \le r \le 2\sin \theta$.

Also, $0 \le r \le 2\sin \theta$ is only possible when $0 \le 2\sin \theta$, i.e. $0 \le \theta \le \pi$.

So, your integral should be $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\sin \theta}\int_{0}^{r}r\,dz\,dr\,d\theta$.

Comment: Where's the 2 going in that first equivalence after we convert to cylindrical?

Comment: ^I accidentally dropped it. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Oops saw your edit late, sorry.

Comment: Yes... once the $2$ is placed before the $sin \theta$ you get the correct answer.